# Visual Studio Code remote target on Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, gdb, visual-studio-code

it is advertised that Visual Studio Code is able to compile and debug on a remote machine.
I've installed VSCode on Ubuntu and I want to compile and debug on the remote Raspberry.
I've setup GDB server on the remote Raspberry but on the Microsoft site it is not detailed how to configure the VSCode IDE in order to connect the remote Raspberry.
There is someone that can give a solution on VSCode (Not on standard Visual Studio)?
Thanks 
  Massimo

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940664/dotnetcore-3-0-remote-debugging-from-visual-studio-2019-ce-on-raspberry-pi-4-i where I had a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that nobody answered my question probably means that nobody use Visual Studio Code with Raspberry.
Then I've investigate myself and I can suggest to use Netbeans that allows the remote development and debugging as well.
It takes less thn 10 minutes to install and configure Netbeans because it include some automatic discovery and configuration automation.
Also this time Microsoft failed !

```
Massimo
```

Comment: I share your pain... once in a while I get fed up with netbeans and try to get a remote build in vscode and always end up in disbelief how can it be so difficult. ...I never succeeded.