# Dotnetcore 3.0 remote debugging from visual studio 2019 CE on Raspberry Pi 4 - insufficient rights

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi

If there was anyone who could tell me how to remote debug a dotnetcore 3.0 console app from visual studio 2019 CE on a raspberry pi 4, I'd be happier.

`plink -ssh -pw raspberry pi@raspberrypi.local "curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -r linux-arm -v latest -l ~/vsdbg"`

is installed and runs on the PI

```
using Iot.Device.CpuTemperature;
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Threading;
namespace Raspi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CpuTemperature temp = new CpuTemperature();
            GpioController ctrl = new GpioController();
            int pin = 4;
            int wait = 5000;
            ctrl.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            int counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The CPU temperature is {temp.Temperature.Celsius}");
                Console.WriteLine("counter=" + counter++);
                ctrl.Write(pin, PinValue.High);
                Thread.Sleep(wait);
                ctrl.Write(pin, PinValue.Low);
                Thread.Sleep(wait);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles without errors. Here some screenshots of the error behaviour:

[vsbdg runs under root account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wv1h.png)
[vsdbg can be found while browsing via ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVwUJ.png)
[And this error comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9lPS.png)
(translated from German) Error while connecting to the process: The .net debugger (vsdbg) doesn't have sufficient rights to debug the process. In order to debug the process, 'vsdbg' must be executed using root rights.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application actually works on the PI.

Comment: I posted the same question on the MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6bbae03b-cfb5-4c90-a631-bf9a6df9668e/dotnetcore-30-remote-debugging-from-visual-studio-2019-ce-on-raspberry-pi-4-insufficient-rights?forum=vscommunityde

Comment: This seems to be offroad debugging: https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug over SSH in Visual Studio.

So what you want to do is effectively this:

- Make your hello world app
- Set breakpoints in it where you want them
- Build the app in debug, self contained
- Deploy the app to your Rapberry Pi (it has to have SSH enabled on the Pi, running something like Raspbian)
- Attach your debugger from VS 2019 to the Pi over SSH.

I wrote a longer article explaining exactly what I did here.  It's the friend link so you don't get hit with Medium's paywall.  It also means we're friends now.

https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/debugging-your-net-core-3-app-on-your-raspberry-pi-with-visual-studio-2019-9662348e79d9?source=friends_link&sk=33e0da85e07e45234a7804d5801110a1

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I added using WinSCP with an environment variable to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.